# AVPlayerItem Swift 2 Nil Checking

Tags: swift, swift2, avfoundation, xcode7, avplayeritem

The code was working fine in Swift 1.2 but when I changed the Xcode 7 (Swift 2), I am getting error, which is written below in `if` statement.

```
let objFirstSound = AVPlayerItem(URL:NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(self.objVowels?.main_sound, ofType: "mp3") ?? ""))

if objFirstSound != nil {
   arrTemp.append(objFirstSound)
}
```

> Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type
>   'AVPlayerItem' and 'NilLiteralConvertible'

So, how can I check `AVPlayerItem`is actually `Nil`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare an Optional:

```
let objFirstSound : AVPlayerItem? = AVPlayerItem(URL:NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(self.objVowels?.main_sound, ofType: "mp3") ?? ""))
```

Then do:

```
if let objFirstSound = objFirstSound
{
    arrTemp.append(objFirstSound)
}
```

Comment: Thanks you solved my issue i was totally forget by this way